# Graphing $\sqrt { -x}$

Tags: complex-numbers

how does my calculator graph ($\sqrt { -x}$.  Since I can't graph a complex number, how does my calculator graph the $\sqrt { -x}$ ?

Comment: How does the graph from your calculator look like? (Compared to [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28-x%29)) If no complex numbers are involved, you'd only consider values $x$ for which $\sqrt{-x}$ is real, i.e. only $x\leq0$

Comment: If $x$ is real, plot you function betwen minus something and zero.

Comment: Hint: $-x$ *can* be positive for *some* values of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not hard to see that. First of all, we have $-x\geq 0$ and so the domain equals negatives real numbers. Consider $-1,-4,-9,-16\ldots$ and it implies that $1,2,3,4,\ldots$. "It is sufficient that you consider $\sqrt x$, then repalce $x\rightarrow -x$"
[image]